# A series of consecutive composite numbers using least common multiple

Tags: number-theory

For arbitrarily large N, we can consider the series $(N + 1)! + 2, (N + 1)! + 3, ..., ( N + 1)! + (N + 1)$, which does not contain a single prime number, is a classic example. But also we can consider the series $LCM(2,3, ..., N + 1) + 2, LCM(2,3, ..., N + 1) + 3, ..., LCM(2,3, ..., N + 1) + (N + 1)$

Will it be the smallest row of length N that does not contain a prime number?

Comment: Have you tried it for small numbers, say $N=4$?

Comment: @dxiv, oops, it doesn't work. $LCM(2, 3, 4, 5) = 60$, but I can consider 24, 25, 26, 27. It feels like it should work for large N

Comment: If you take the [squarefree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) part of the $\operatorname{lcm}$ you'll get a smaller sequence. For example in the case $N=4$ you will find $32,33,34,35$, which _is_ smaller than the $\operatorname{lcm}$-based sequence, but still not the shortest.

Comment: Related: [Finding an integer (if one exists) $n$ such that $n$, $n+1$, $n+2$, $n+3$, $n+4$ are all composite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804191/finding-an-integer-if-one-exists-n-such-that-n-n1-n2-n3-n4). See also OEIS [A008950](https://oeis.org/A008950).

Comment: @dxiv, thank you